# Type hint issues with Union on a class method signature

Tags: python, oop, mypy, python-typing

I am getting a squiggly line under the `Union` keyword below with "syntax error in type" on VSCode's `mypy` and I think the error message is related to something about the method signature, but can't figure it out. I've tried both `Union` and `Optional`.

```py
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, username: str = None, password: str = None):
        self.uid = ""
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.image = ""
        self.images: dict = {}

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_username(
        cls: "User", username: str
    ) -> Union["User", None]:
        user_document = await current_app.dbc.user.find_one(
            {"username": username}
        )
        if not user_document:
            return None
        else:
            cls.uid = str(user_document["uid"])
            cls.username = user_document["username"]
            cls.password = user_document["password"]
            cls.image = user_document["image"]
            cls.images = {}

            image_dict = cls._image_url_from_image_ts(cls.uid, cls.image)
            cls.images["image_url_raw"] = image_dict["image_url_raw"]
            cls.images["image_url_xlg"] = image_dict["image_url_xlg"]
            cls.images["image_url_lg"] = image_dict["image_url_lg"]
            cls.images["image_url_sm"] = image_dict["image_url_sm"]

            return cls
```

As you can see the method can return `None` or a class instance.

The error in VSCode reads:

```
syntax error in type comment mypy(error) (class) Union No quick fixes available
```

I can also reproduce running `mypy` on the terminal:

```
$ mypy .\user\models.py
user\models.py:18: error: syntax error in type comment
```

Comment: ` Union["User", None]` --> ` Union[User, None]`

Comment: The problem could be VSCode not liking a string, rather than a type, as the type parameter.

Comment: @balderman `Union["User", None]` should be legal, though: that's how you handle forward references (unless you use `from __future__ import annotations` or are using Python 3.10 or later).

Comment: It would be odd if the string was causing an issue. Afaik, strings in that context are outlined in one of the typing PEPs.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but the type of `cls` should be `Type["User"]`, not `"User"`.

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove the `async`?  Wondering if it's a version issue.

Comment: @chepner I tried `Optional["User"]` with the same error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with mypy 0.910. See also the [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=ae0287c8332c1f9ef007adfba2629f32); none of the playground versions reproduce the issue, either.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? "type comment" suggests one of those old-style type hints used that were embedded in comments. This code doesn't have any of those though. Make sure you don't have a comment in that area that may be being mis-interpreted.

Comment: Mypy complains about line 18, but it's not clear which line is line 18.  That information is missing.

Answer (score -2):

So it turns out I had some weird installation issues. I was running VSCode using a `pipenv` shell that wasn't running the same version of `mypy` specified on the `Pipfile`. I was also running `pipenv` using `python -m pipenv`, instead of top level `pipenv`. So I cleaned all the `pip` packages, installed `pipenv` and upgraded to `mypy` 0.780 and the following code works:

```
from quart import current_app
from typing import Union, Type

from settings import IMAGES_URL


class User(object):
    def __init__(self, username: str = None, password: str = None):
        self.uid = ""
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.image = ""
        self.images: dict = {}

    @classmethod
    async def get_user_by_username(
        cls, username: str
    ) -> Union[Type["User"], None]:
        user_document = await current_app.dbc.user.find_one(
            {"username": username}
        )
        if not user_document:
            return None
        else:
            cls.uid = str(user_document["uid"])
            cls.username = user_document["username"]
            cls.password = user_document["password"]
            cls.image = user_document["image"]
            cls.images = {}

            image_dict = cls._image_url_from_image_ts(cls.uid, cls.image)
            cls.images["image_url_raw"] = image_dict["image_url_raw"]
            cls.images["image_url_xlg"] = image_dict["image_url_xlg"]
            cls.images["image_url_lg"] = image_dict["image_url_lg"]
            cls.images["image_url_sm"] = image_dict["image_url_sm"]

            return cls
```